# error in c++ matrix*vector multiplication

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, function-definition

I need a function that multiply a matrix and a vector (Matrix*vector)

It takes in a matrix A and a vector B, with int describing the dimensions. Somehow it isn't running correctly. Any help??

```
void Multiply(double *res, double **A, double *B, int ARows, int ACols, int BRows)
{

    if (ACols !=BRows)

    {

        return;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ACols; i++)
    {
        res[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < BRows; j++)
        {
            res[i] += A[i][j]*B[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ARows` be used in there somewhere?

Comment: It should be Arows in the first for, not Acols. Note that res will have the same number of rows as A,  has it been allocated correctly?

Comment: Perhaps [`std::valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) could help.

Comment: [Row major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARows; i++)
{
    res[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < ACols; j++)
    {
        res[i] += A[i][j]*B[j];
    }
}
```

It would be better if the function returns a boolean value that signals whether the function execution was successful for example

```
bool Multiply(double *res, double **A, double *B, int ARows, int ACols, int BRows)
{    
   bool success = ACols == BRows;

    if ( success )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ARows; i++)
        {
            res[i] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < ACols; j++)
            {
               res[i] += A[i][j]*B[j];
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Instead of the manually written loops you could use the standard algorithm `std::inner_product` declared in the header `<numeric>`.

Comment: A.k.a `res[i] = std::inner_product(A[i], A[i] + ACols, B, 0);`